# footer won't show below routes with container

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap, react-spring

I've got a footer that I am trying to fix. I am trying to get react-spring animation to work when I scroll down. with the below code, the footer is appearing at the middle of the screen. I know the problem has got to do with my container be placed wrongly and home.tsx is in a 'fixed position. However, if I change those, I won't be able to get react-spring animation to work the way I wanted it to. It seems that I have forgotten something very fundamental here. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

`App.js`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container-fluid'>
      <BrowserRouter>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={'/'} render={() => {
                    return <Redirect to={'/home'}/>
                }}/>
                <Route exact path={'/home'} component={Home} className='container'/>
                <Route exact path={'/page2'} component={page2}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in my home component,

home.tsx

```
const Home = () => {

    const Text = ({ children, offset, pos, start, end }: any) => {
        const [transform] = useState(() =>
          offset.interpolate({ range: [start, end], output: [100, 0], extrapolate: 'clamp' }).interpolate((s: any) => `translate3d(${s}px,0,0)`),
        )
        const [opacity] = useState(() => offset.interpolate([start, end], [0, 1]))
        return <animated.div style={{ left: 20, top: `${pos * 100}vh`, transform, opacity, color: 'blue', fontSize: 25 }}>{children}</animated.div>
      };
    const [{ scroll }, set] = useSpring(() => ({ scroll: 0 }))
    const onScroll = useCallback(e => void set({ scroll: e.target.scrollTop / (window.innerHeight / 2) }), [set]);
     
    return (
        <div onScroll={onScroll} style={{overflowY: 'scroll', position: 'fixed', height: '100%'}}  >
            <Text offset={scroll} pos={0} start={0} end={0.5} children="<Longg line of TEXT>" />
            <Text offset={scroll} pos={0.5} start={0.5} end={1} children="<Longg line of TEXT>" />
            <Text offset={scroll} pos={1} start={1} end={1.5} children="<Longg line of TEXT>" />
            <Text offset={scroll} pos={1.5} start={1.5} end={2} children="<Longg line of TEXT>" />                
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

What I want to achieve is

```
+--------------------+
|       header       |
+--------------------+
|       Content      |
|       Content      |
|       Content      |
|       Content      |
+--------------------+
|       footer       |
+--------------------+
```

but I am getting this

```
+--------------------+
|       header       |
+--------------------+
+------ Content -----+
|       footer       |
+------ Content -----+
+------ Content -----+
+------ Content -----+
```

where the head and footer is fixed at the top.

**Update:**

I guess the quick fix solution for now is to have both header and footer to be inside each and every component. base on the bootstrap fundamentals of

```
const Home = () => {
    <div className="container">
      <div> header </div>
      <div> content </div>
      <div> footer </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You should not define a component inside another, so move `Text` outside of `Home` and pass props.  The way it is, the `Text` gets re-created on every render of `Home` and loses its state.  I'm not sure If there's enough code here to analyze.  I am seeing `Footer` on top and negative opacity values for the texts, which only come into view after scrolling: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-scrolling-ounx9?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for your reply. I guess the only quick fix solution is to have both header and footer placed in each and every component.